# Prometheus Stats Collection - Do I need to expose endpoint?

Tags: prometheus

If I need to use Prometheus do I have to always expose endpoint for it to **scrape** my service to gather metrics. If I am running a backend service why would I want to expose an endpoint just for stats collection.

I am looking for an alternate or a very optimal way to work with this. Anyone has any thoughts on implementation?

One of the alternates I thought is of having a generic metrics collector collecting stats from all the applications over messaging and then the collector writes metrics onto Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Prometheus does the scraping of targets out of the box, so you will be recreating a main feature of Prometheus itself. Quite often you will have the generic NodeExporter and an application specific exporter (e.g. DB or JMX) on an second port. Prometheus UI shows you unhealthy scrape targets in a very nice view.

Of course you should invest on adding authentication on the `/metrics` endpoint.

If you have many targets to scrape I highly recommend using the Prometheus auto-discovery features in combination with automated infrastructure provisioning (e.g. Ansible) so you don't have to maintain scrape targets manually. For this to work your Prometheus has to be in the same network segment though.

Comment: But having a backend service which is running fast and furious expose endpoints seems to be an overhead. I am crunching millions of events under a minute and performance is what I care about most. Thoughts?

Comment: But if you want to have that service internal data you have to expose it somehow. If you don't want to touch your service code itself, you could use a generic exporter like JMX if on Java. These exporters are usually lightweight tools that just create the metrics endpoint for Prometheus to scrape. A big list can be found here: https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

Comment: my main motive is not to introduce something which can quitely keep on profiling my application and lead to unwanted situation. I am writing a high performance platform which has total 6 threads affinitized to 6 cores and don't want something invisible snapshotting my application without my knowledge and set frequency.